# How can I set run parameter in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, parameters

I know how to set run parameter in eclipse(Run tap -> Run Configuration -> Argument)

I want to do same thing in intellij but there is no Run Configuration Menu How can I set parameter while running app in intellij?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `Program Arguments` and `Environment Variables` under `Run | Edit Configurations... | select your configuration`:

[image]

See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html#createExplicitly for more information.